# DIV is centered in Desktop browsers, not on iPhone - why?

Tags: html, ios, css

Hi: I'm working on a very simple page hosting an AWeber signup form, intending it to be viewed on mobile devices. It's here:

http://radionowheremusic.com/phase2.html

On my MacBook, the div containing the form is centered in the page; when viewed in either Chrome or Safari on an iPhone 5, though, it's skewed off to the right.

I've tried all sorts of positioning and centering CSS tricks, but none of them have worked. In fact, nearly all of a varied set of approaches have had no effect, leading me to believe there's something downstream in the code that I don't see/can't understand. Probably something very simple. Any input would be great - thanks!

Comment: Remove the padding style from the `body` and it will align better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`margin:0 auto` will center the form.

Remove the 20px padding from the body. Your iDevice is pushing your form 20px to the right.

Comment: Knew it waS something simple, but who knows how long it'd have taken me to find it. Thanks!